# Form in Javascript and pass variables to php without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, xmlhttprequest

I'm new on this form.
So I'm currently working on a music player website. In this case I want to upload a file in the server. To do this, I want to have a Javascript form and at the click of the button it will execute a function which opens a XMLHttpRequest to another page (upload2.php). In that page I want to "convert" the variables of the form and insert them in my MySQL Database. All without refreshing the page.
How can I do it?
I started writing this code (upload and ajax calls functions works correctly, just want to make a javascript form) :

```
MAIN PAGE:

<html>
<head>
   <script>

    function reqListener () {
        document.getElementById("content1").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }

       function func_upload2() {
       var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlhttp.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
       xmlhttp.open("POST", "upload2.php", true);
       xmlhttp.send();        
   }


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content1">
<h1> UPLOAD </h1>

<form name="myForm"><br>
<input type=file name="pic" accept=".mp3"> <br>

<button type="button" id="upload" name="btn-upload"                                                                                                              
onclick="func_upload2()"> UPLOAD </button><br> 
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

upload2.php:

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
        $namefile=$_FILES['pic']['name'];
        $pic = rand(1000,100000) ."-".$_FILES['pic']['name'];
        $pic =$_FILES['pic']['name'];
        $pic_loc = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];

        $path="Tracks/".$_SESSION['IdUser'];
        if(!is_dir($path))
           {
               Mkdir("Tracks/".$_SESSION['IdUser']."/",0777);
           }
        $folder="Tracks/".$_SESSION['IdUser']."/";
        if(move_uploaded_file($pic_loc,$folder.$pic))
        {
            $path1=$folder.$namefile;
            echo $path1;

            $insert = $connect->query("INSERT INTO Tracks (Name,   
            Path, IdUser) VALUES ('".$namefile."', '".$path1."',
            '".$_SESSION['IdUser']."');"); 
            echo "Uploaded!"; 
        }
        else
        {
           echo "Not uploaded";
        }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX file upload PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php)